# How is the textual discrepancy between Surah 19:67 and 15:26 explained?

Tags: contradiction

According to a website at the top of a google search, there is a contradiction in the Quran between Surah 19:67 and 15:26.

[Carm](https://carm.org/islam/contradictions-in-the-quran/)

> In Surah 19:67, it states that man was created out of nothing.  In 15:26, man is created from clay.

**Question**

How is the textual discrepancy between Surah 19:67 and 15:26 explained?

Comment: [19:67](https://quran.com/19/67?translations=20) says that man was nothing, it does not say that he was *created* from nothing. And even if we assume that for a moment, it is correct since clay is nothing of importance and itself was created ultimately from nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asalamo Aliakum,

I think the person has misinterpreted 19:67:

> أَوَلَا يَذْكُرُ ٱلْإِنسَـٰنُ أَنَّا خَلَقْنَـٰهُ مِن قَبْلُ
> وَلَمْيَكُ شَيْـًۭٔا  ٦٧

Which translates to: **Do ˹such˺ people not remember that We created them before, when they were nothing?**

This does not mean that human were created from nothing rather it means that Allah is the one who created Human-kind or brought humans into existence when they were non-existing(not a thing which could be thought of or mentioned).

(can also resurrect them )

Which is an answer/counter-question to (19:66) :

> وَيَقُولُ ٱلْإِنسَـٰنُ أَءِذَا مَا مِتُّ لَسَوْفَ أُخْرَجُ حَيًّا

Which translates to : **Yet ˹some˺ people ask ˹mockingly˺, “After I die, will I really be raised to life again?”**

Here is a claimed **Ibn Kathir** tafsir on 19:66,67:

*(And man says: "When I am dead, shall I then be raised up alive'' Does not man remember that We created him before, while he was nothing) Allah uses the beginning of creation as a proof for its repetition. This means that He, the Exalted, created the human being while he was nothing. So can he not repeat this creation after the human had actually become something.*